# Best subset of variables to perform discriminant analysis

Tags: feature-selection, discriminant-analysis

I have around 33 variables, and 300 observations, although of some variables there are some missing data.

I would like to obtain the best subset of variables which can separate the best 3 categories in a multidimensional space. I thought about applying some discriminant analysis, but as there is some missing data (I would rather not to perform imputation) I am having some trouble.

How would you recommend me to obtain the best subset of variables which can separate these three groups?

Comment: Currently your question is a bit unclear. Is the main problem selecting a subset of variables, or is the main problem having variables with missing data? Did I read it correctly that - if you didn't have those missing data you would simply perform discriminant analysis and that would answer your question?

Comment: The problem is of both sides. If I didn't have the missing, I would perform the discriminant analysis, but also I would like to know the best variables to use for the discriminant analysis